# Create constraints between views in different static UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have some static UITableViewCells in a storyboard:

[image: Static Cells in a UITableView]

I'd like the textfields on the right of the bottom four cells to align left. There is already a constraint between Password and Some Password, since Password is the longest label on the screen. I'd like the other textfields to align with that one.

I can't seem to multi-select the textfields to add an alignment constraint, nor can I drag from on textfield to the other and get a set of constraint choices.

Is there a way to do this in Xcode, or is the only way to do this creating outlets to these static cells and adding the constraints in code?

Comment: Seems that this is still not possible

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with your problem by aligning all the labels to right and all the textfields to left manually, then applied the following constraints.

- Horizontal space constraints between each label and the textfield.
- Removed the constant width constraint of each textfield.

So the textfield is aligned to left with flexible width 
and the label is aligned to right with fixed with.

and it worked well for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that doesn't really help as the app's design calls for left aligned fields.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this in code. Just give each label except the longest one a fixed width constraint. Then make outlets of these constraints in your view controller. Then in viewDidLayoutSubviews you set the width of these constraints to the width of the frame of the longest label, like:

```
nameLabelWidthConstraint.constant = passwordLabel.frame.size.width
locationLabelWidthConstraint.constant = passwordLabel.frame.size.width
emailLabelWidthConstraint.constant = passwordLabel.frame.size.width
```

You might want to right align the labels, depends on what you want of course.

If the names of the labels are dynamic (like when supporting more languages), then you might want to check which label is the longest in code too. In that case you don't want to set the with constraints in storyboard. Instead you'll need to first check the width of the frames of each label. Find the highest number and then add the width constraints to each label with that width in code.